# Collapse Cells until a condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to collapse categories until a condition is met.  I have simulated some data.  In cases in which "N" is less than 10 I want to take the sum of "wt" grouped by that level of group2 and the next highest level.  On row one - "N" equals 0, so I want to sum "wt" for row one and row two.  The sum of "N" in row 4 and row 5 is also less than 10 so I want to sum "wt" for rows 3,4 and 5.  I know how to use group by in dplyr but don't know how to do it stipulated under conditions.

```
a <-expand.grid( group2=c( 1:5  ) , group1=c( "F","M" ) )
a$N <- c( 0 ,12, 15, 2, 5 ,9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 15)
a$wt =c( 12 ,23 ,45 , 5 , 1 , 11 ,8 , 9 ,12, 27 )
a$row <- 1:10
```

So I have thought about writing a loop for each observation to look to the next row - but that seems clunky.

without a group by argument I just get the sum of all the places where"N" is than 10

```
a %>%
filter( N < 10 ) %>%
mutate(   Wt2 = sum( wt )  )
```

Comment: Why when `row 4 and row 5 is also less than 10` you want to sum row 3, 4, and 5? Notice that row 3 is in prior to row 4 so I think it is not the `next highest level`. Could you shared your desired output as a data frame?

Comment: Well row three has more than 10, so I would skip that.  But 4 is less than 10, so I merge with 5.  4 and 5 together are still less than 10, so I want to merge with 3 (since there is no level 6) in this example.

Comment: OK. I understand the steps you described until last one. Why do you merge with row 3 as it is not smaller than 10?

Comment: He's saying that he would merge with row 6 if it was more than 10, but since there is no 6, the highest one it can merge with is 3. Think of it as each group is a cohort and he's trying to aggregate the small ones (`N` being the size) into the adjacent larger ones so that all cohorts have at least 10 people. When he does that, though, he has to aggregate the weight (`wt`) as well associated with the smaller groups that are being merged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

First, we can design a function, `check_fun` to see if there are any two or more consecutive rows with `N` below 10. `TRUE` indicates aggregation is needed.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

check_fun <- function(df){
  df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(Below10 = rleid(N < 10)) %>%
    filter(N < 10) %>%
    count(group1, Below10)
  return(any(df2$n > 1))
}

check_fun(a)
# [1] TRUE
```

We can then design a second function, `aggregate_fun1`, which conduct the aggregation to the next row.

```
aggregate_fun1 <- function(df){
  df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(Below10 = rleid(N < 10)) %>%
    group_by(Below10) %>%
    mutate(Index1 = ifelse(N >= 10, row_number(), NA)) %>%
    mutate(Index2 = ifelse(N < 10, row_number(), NA)) %>%
    mutate(Index2 = ifelse(Index2 == 2, 1, Index2)) %>%
    group_by(group1, Below10, Index1, Index2) %>%
    summarize(N = sum(N), wt = sum(wt)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-Below10, -Index1, -Index2)
  return(df2)
} 

a2 <- aggregate_fun1(a)
a2
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   group1     N    wt
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 F       0    12.0 
# 2 F      12.0  23.0 
# 3 F      15.0  45.0 
# 4 F       7.00  6.00
# 5 M       9.00 11.0 
# 6 M      10.0   8.00
# 7 M      11.0   9.00
# 8 M      12.0  12.0 
# 9 M      15.0  27.0
```

We can apply `aggregate_fun1` iteratively until there are no any two or more consecutive rows with `N` below 10. We then need a third function, `aggregate_fun2`, to aggregate those single rows with `N` below 10 to the next or the previous row. Here I designed this function to take the next row as the priority compared to the previous row.

```
aggregate_fun2 <- function(df){
  df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(Flag1 = ifelse(N < 10, row_number(), NA)) %>%
    mutate(Flag2 = ifelse(is.na(Flag1) & !is.na(lag(Flag1)), lag(Flag1), NA)) %>%
    mutate(Flag3 = ifelse(is.na(Flag1) & !is.na(lead(Flag1)), lead(Flag1), NA)) %>%
    mutate(Flag4 = coalesce(.$Flag1, .$Flag2, .$Flag3)) %>%
    mutate(Flag4 = ifelse(is.na(Flag4), row_number(), Flag4)) %>%
    group_by(group1, Flag4) %>%
    summarize(N = sum(N), wt = sum(wt)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-Flag4)
  return(df2)
}

a3 <- aggregate_fun2(a2)
a3
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   group1     N    wt
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 F       12.0 35.0 
# 2 F       22.0 51.0 
# 3 M       19.0 19.0 
# 4 M       11.0  9.00
# 5 M       12.0 12.0 
# 6 M       15.0 27.0
```

In this example, `a3` is the final output.

We can combine all the three function together with a while loop on `check_fun` and `aggregate_fun1`. If the condition is satisfied, we can then use `aggregate_fun2` to calculate the final output. I called this function `aggregate_fun`.

```
aggregate_fun <- function(df){
  while(check_fun(df)){
    df <- df %>% aggregate_fun1()
  }
  df2 <- df %>% aggregate_fun2()
  return(df2)
}
```

By applying `aggregate_fun` to `a`, we can get the output.

```
aggregate_fun(a)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   group1     N    wt
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 F       12.0 35.0 
# 2 F       22.0 51.0 
# 3 M       19.0 19.0 
# 4 M       11.0  9.00
# 5 M       12.0 12.0 
# 6 M       15.0 27.0
```